# Lambda expression delegates in behavior

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, attachedbehaviors

I have an attached behavior that used on a listbox, it should automatically select the first element in the list, if the list contains only one element.

The only way that I have found to hook the listbox when the list changes, is to use the listbox' itemcollections CollectionChanged event:

```
private static void ListenToItemsCollectionChange(ListBox listBox)
{
    var collection = (INotifyCollectionChanged)listBox.Items;

    collection.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) => SelectAndSetFocusToFirstElement(listBox);
}
```

The problem now, is that there is no way of unsubscribing from the event, which potentially leads to multiple invokations of `SelectAndSetFocusToFirstelement( )`.

The normal solution to this, is to not use lambdas. But then I would loose my listbox, which I need for selecting the first element.

Any suggestions on how this can be solved?

[Full code](http://git://gist.github.com/1044691.git)

Answer (score 2):

A Lambda is just a shortcut for a delegate, so you can rewrite the lambda as

```
NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs collectionChangedDelegate = (sender, arg) =>
{SelectAndSetFocusToFirstElement(listBox)};
```

then you can add to the collection changed event

```
collection.CollectionChanged += collectionChangedDelegate
```

and remove

```
collection.CollectionChanged -= collectionChangedDelegate
```

Comment: But where do you keep the reference to collectionChangedDelegate between calls to `ListenToItemsCollectionChange`?

Comment: When I've done stuff like that before I've used a class level dictionary to hold references to various delegates and added a handler to the Unloaded event of the control to remove the event delegate (and it's associated reference in the dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

I got a little bit confused what do You meand by "But then I would loose my listbox" ?

Maybe this solution will be sufficient

You could keep the event handler in temporary variable like that

```
  EventHandler handler = (a, b) => { }; // You must use aproperiate delegate
    collection.CollectionChanged += handler
```

and if You want to unsubscribe You could use -= handler

Comment: The eventhandler for CollectionChanged gives you no reference to the listbox - only the collection. By using lambda, you still have access to local variables, and can there for access the listbox passed as parameter to the `ListenToItemsCollectionChage()`-method.

Comment: And how would you use an reference to an event handler stored in a temporary variable from another place in time?